# MYSQL how to find in array column

Tags: mysql, sql

i need fin in a colum type array in MYSQL example :

```
  Select * from item where types = 4 
  where types is an array column example types = (1,2,3,4);
```

thanks.

Comment: AFAIK MySQL doesn't support array type. You can work around this issue with predicate LIKE and performing a search within your text.

Comment: Please show some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you want to search multiples IDs, you need to do the following:

```
Select * from item where types IN (1,2,3,4);
```